# Retaining form inputs upon a jquery datatable refresh

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables

I've been looking all over for an answer to this and haven't found anything to fit the bill...

My database schema incorporates a template which contains all the constants required for a transaction and transactions, which contain data for each individual transaction. There is a one-to-many relationship between the template and the transactions (one template may have many transactions)

I'm using a jQuery datatable as a form with 3 input fields (transaction information) for each row (template). Clicking a submit button sends the information entered into the table to the controller which then creates the individual transaction records.

An option on the page allows a user to input a new row (template) using a dialog style form. When a user enters a new template, the table is redrawn and the new template shows up with the 3 fields for creating a transaction.

My question is this:
The user enters information into a row (or more) to create a new transaction(s). They decide they need a new template and so, create one using the option noted above. Upon submission of the new template form, the datatable redraws but I loose all the transactional information I've input. Is there a way to retain the information that was input when the table is redrawn?

I'd considered using the "save as you type" plugin but find that the datatable doesn't seem to set up a standard HTML form (i.e. no form tag), so there doesn't appear to be any way to designate a form id. Using session or cookies would be fine, I'm just not sure where to start.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as would an outright "you just set this parameter" answer.

Comment: When a new template is created, could you prevent the table redraw?  You could create the new table row in the dom so it looks like the table has redrawn - (ie use jquery to build a row and add it). When the data is submitted for real, the datatable would then redraw.

Comment: Please post some code or create a minimal working example on jsFiddle, otherwise you will get generic answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Withdrawing question. Decided to go another route.